# OleDB Exception - C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have below connection code to Access DB. I can debug and see the connection string along with parameter values but it says `"Data type mismatch in criteria expression"` at `myAccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
using (OleDbConnection thisConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionname))
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO HornerPluginResults([Entity],[Date],[Depth],[FormationTemp])VALUES(@Entity,@Date,@Depth,@FormationTemp)";
                OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, thisConnection);

                myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entity", model.entity.Name);
                myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", model.TableResults[0].todaydate);
                myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Depth", model.Depth);
                myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormationTemp", formationtemp);
                thisConnection.Open();
                myAccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

The access table is defined as:

[image]

I am not sure where is the issue!

Comment: Can you show us the class/type of `model` from your code?

Comment: AddWithValue is well know to fire these kind of problems. It creates a parameter with a datatype inferred from the value given. There are a lot of conversions going on if the parameter datatype doesn't match the column type. Use the Add method instead of AddWithValue or double check your inputs

Comment: iirc you can't use named placeholders (`@XXX`) try replacing them in the string with `values (?, ?, ?, ...` and  use `myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(model.entity.Name);` in the correct order.

Comment: @AlexK. - System.Data.OleDb *allows* named placeholders but it still treats them as strictly positional, so using the `?` placeholder is recommended but not strictly required.